# How do I move forward in the direction I am pointing in a 3d world?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos3d

I am using Cocos3D. I have a camera (which acts as the first-person viewed player in a world with only a spinning "hello, world" and a spinning earth. I have made it possible for the camera to point in any direction, and I have got it to move, but how do I get the camera/player to move forward in the direction he is pointing? (He does not go up or down, i.e. his y position does not change).

Comment: What format is the information stored that tells you the rotation of the "player"?  Is it a vector (i.e. [1.2, 0.4, 2.1] or something similar)?

Comment: Actually, I have recently found a built in command which does this for me, but I still have no idea how it works. And the Player.rotation.y gives you the players current direction (360 degrees or -360)

Answer (score 0):

I note this is quite an old question - hopefully this answer helps someone!

You need to get the rotation angle of your camera, convert that to radians and use trigonometry to get the new X-Z coordinates. Tell your camera to move to those coordinates and presto, the player has moved forward!

```
CC3Camera *cam = self.activeCamera;

CC3Rotator *rotator = cam.rotator;
CC3Vector ro = rotatoooor.rotation;
CC3Vector loc = cam.globalLocation;

// If the -90 is left off, you go left/right and not forward
float roA = rotator.rotationAngle-90;

// Bug in rotationAngle? Need this as 315 angle reports as 45
int roI = ro.y;
int diff = roA+90 - roI;
if (diff == 0 && roI == 45)
    roA = 315-90;

double theta = roA * M_PI/180; // Convert to radians
/*
 x = d cos a
 z = d sin a
 */
double sinA = sin(theta);
double cosA = cos(theta);
double newX = distance*cosA + loc.x;
double newZ = distance*sinA + loc.z;

CC3Vector newTo = cc3v(newX, loc.y, newZ); // Pass this to your camera
```